# Help on a conditional probability exercise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was trying to solve an exercise but I am having some problems on finding the solution. This is the problem we are asked to solve:

> We know that a printer made 147 mistakes when printing a 490-page book. Assuming his way of working does not change, how can we estimate the likelihood that he will print a 10-page booklet without errors?

I've tried to solve it, but I think I'm missing some points. Could you please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, this seems to be a homework assignment, I will only give instructions, you have to solve it on your own.

1, Calculate the **probability of finding an error in a single page** from given data. It will be equal to total number of errors divided by total number of pages printed.

2, Then calculate **the probability of not making an error in a single page**. It will be complementary to the probability calculated in the above step.

3, Finally, calculate **probability of not making an error in ten pages.** It will the value calculated in the second step raised to the power of ten.